# recursive backtracking makeChange

Tags: java, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

Write a method makeChange that uses recursive backtracking to find all ways to make change for a given amount of money using pennies (1 cent), nickels (5 cents), dimes (10 cents), and quarters (25 cents).

For example, when making change for 37 cents, you could use:

- 1 quarter
- 1 dime and 2 pennies
- 3 dimes and 7 pennies
- Or other combinations.

Your method should accept a single parameter: The amount of cents for which to make change.

Your method's output should be a sequence of all combinations of each type of coin that add up to that amount, one per line.

For example, if the client code contained the following call:

```
System.out.println(" P  N  D  Q");
System.out.println("------------");
makeChange(28);
```

The overall output generated should be the following:

```
 P  N  D  Q
------------ [3, 0, 0, 1] [3, 1, 2, 0] [3, 3, 1, 0] [3, 5, 0, 0] [8, 0, 2, 0] [8, 2, 1, 0] [8, 4, 0, 0] [13, 1, 1, 0] [13, 3, 0, 0] [18, 0, 1, 0] [18, 2, 0, 0] [23, 1, 0, 0] [28, 0, 0, 0]
```

A key insight toward solving this problem is the notion of looking at each denomination of coin (penny, nickel, etc.) and trying all possible numbers of that coin (1 penny, 2 pennies, ..., 28 pennies) to see what combinations can be made starting with that choice. For example, in the output above, first all the combinations that begin with 3 pennies are shown, then all combinations that begin with 8 pennies, and so on.

Since backtracking involves exploring a set of choices, you should represent the coin denominations in some way in your code. We suggest keeping a list of all coin denomination values for processing. As you process various coin values, you can modify the contents of this list. The template below is a starting point (you can copy/paste it into your code text box to get started):

```
public static void makeChange(int amount) {
    List coinValues = new LinkedList();
    coinValues.add(1);    // penny
    coinValues.add(5);    // nickel
    coinValues.add(10);   // dime
    coinValues.add(25);   // quarter

// ... your code goes here ...
```

You may assume that the amount of change passed to your method is non-negative, but it could exceed 100.

So here is my code:

```
public static void makeChange(int amount){
    int[] acc = new int[4];
    makeChange(amount, acc);
}

private static void makeChange(int amount, int[] acc){
    if(amount == 0){
        System.out.print("[" + acc[0]);
        for(int i = 1; i < 4; i++){
            System.out.print(", " + acc[i]);
        }
        System.out.print("]");
        System.out.println();
    }
    if(amount > 0){
        acc[0]++;
        makeChange(amount - 1, acc);
        acc[0]--;
        acc[1]++;
        makeChange(amount - 5, acc);
        acc[1]--;
        acc[2]++;
        makeChange(amount - 10, acc);
        acc[2]--;
        acc[3]++;
        makeChange(amount - 25, acc);
        acc[3]--;
    }
}
```

and its output for the call of makeChange(28):

```
[28, 0, 0, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 0, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[23, 1, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
[18, 2, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 3, 0, 0]
[13, 1, 1, 0]
```

...(there are hundreds of lines of output)

Can somebody tell me why duplicate output is produced?
Lots of thanks!

Comment: Did you step through your code in the debugger? What did you find?

Comment: See there's this weird problem with my computer and it cannot debug at the momment...So I could only run the code with in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Putting in simpler terms you arrived at same solutions through different routes. Now the way code is written the order matters.

**Simple case to understand:**

Suppose we want change of 6. Now `1 + 5 = 5 + 1`.

So you will have [1,1,0,0] twice in solution.

Way 1: You subtracted 1 first, then 5 and reached 0.

Way 2: You subtracted 5 first, then 1 and reached 0.

To get only unique solutions use `HashSet` or `TreeSet` to store solution maybe as `ArrayList` (but not an array) instead of printing at the base condition. Print all the solutions at the end together.

Another way is you can add a third parameter that indicates what coin did you use last. You will use coins with denomination `>=` to the last used coin. This ensures that solutions will be unique.